# Ubuntu 18.04 does not boot without nomodeset with last message "switching to inteldrmfb from efi vga"

Tags: drivers, kernel, intel-graphics, amd-graphics

After either an overheating accident or an unfortunate update, my Ubuntu 18.04 install only boots with `nomodeset` kernel parameter.
That's not OK since `radeon` driver does not want to run with `nomodeset`:

```
$ sudo modprobe -f radeon 
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'radeon': Exec format error
$ dmesg |tail -2          
[  168.641843] [drm] VGACON disable radeon kernel modesetting.
[  168.641865] [drm:radeon_init [radeon]] *ERROR* No UMS support in radeon module!
```

If I don't enable `nomodeset`, boot process freezes after the `switching to inteldrmfb from efi vga` message.
I would really like to boot my system normally without `nomodeset`.

I was using the `linux-generic-hwe-18.04` kernel. The one that was previously was booting successfully and now fails is `Linux version 5.4.0-90-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-026) (gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)) #101~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 22 09:25:04 UTC 2021 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-90.101~18.04.1-generic 5.4.148)`

I tried several different kernels from [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/) (5.4.189, 5.4.70) but that didn't help: the boot freezes at the same point.
I also tried other kernel arguments that were suggested in situations like this: `amdgpu.dc=0` and `intel_iommu=on` but that didn't help.

Maybe there is something else that breaks boot instead of the kernel?

My graphic cards:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [144d:c0d8]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at bfc00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel modules: i915

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] [1002:6840] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] [144d:c0d8]
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 11
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [disabled] [size=256M]
    Memory at c0220000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=128K]
    I/O ports at 3000 [disabled] [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at c0200000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Capabilities: [150] Advanced Error Reporting
    Kernel modules: radeon
```

Comment: Hello. Good it is fixed but you do not to do something. What you are calling an update needs to be made as an answer. Use the button at the bottom of the question called answer own question and put the answer there so everyone can see it.

Comment: @David made it an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Booting with `module_blacklist=radeon` kernel argument works without a hiccup, and I'm even able to use dual display I was afraid I wouldn't be able to anymore. Guess my Radeon card is no longer functional, and when the driver tries to enable it, the system freezes.